# How to use an Arduino Speaker module with DFPlayer Mini?

Tags: speaker

I've bought an [Arduino speaker module](https://aliexpress.com/item/1005001728930766.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.29d8b723i5oVcV&algo_pvid=2b423ecb-737d-4cfb-aa5b-d9bf775acb1c&algo_expid=2b423ecb-737d-4cfb-aa5b-d9bf775acb1c-31&btsid=0b8b15f516051880750104598e2019&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_,searchweb201603_). How should I connect the module, if I want to use it with DFPlayer Mini? The problem is that the speaker module has 3 pins: `GND`, `VCC`, and `IN`; though the DFPlayer Mini has 2 pins for connecting a speaker: `SPEAKER +` and `SPEAKER -`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DFPlayer already has an amplifier on it, so you can connect the speaker directly.

You can just leave out the board you bought from AliExpress, and only use the speaker.

Comment: Can I use the board with the DFPlayer? The DFPlayer has no filtering condensers, I'd like to use the ones bundled with the Speaker Module.

Comment: In that case you can use the DAC_R or DAC_L output of the DFPlayer, and connect that to the IN pin of your speaker amplifier board.

Comment: so I need to connect the board's GND to the player's GND, the board's VCC with the player's VCC, and the board`s IN with the player's DAC_R?

Comment: Yes. Though I'm still a bit puzzle why you'd want to go that route.

Comment: Gerben, do I need to run the `startDAC` command in my sketch?

Comment: I don't know. I don't think you have to change anything.